# Parsing a string into an imported object variable name in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of svg files, each file containing the logo of a sports team.

Within a component I get a JSON object with the list of teams, each team has id, abbreviation, name and so forth. I want to display the logo of each team next to its name so I am importing all of the svg files into the component and giving them a variable name of abbreviation + "_Logo" and I am coding it like so:

```
import Abbr1_Logo from '../resources/img/team1_logo.svg';  
import Abbr2_Logo from '../resources/img/team2_logo.svg';  
import Abbr3_Logo from '../resources/img/team3_logo.svg';  
...

let teams = result.data.map(t => {  
    return (  
        <li key={t.id}>  
            <img src={t.abbreviation + "_Logo"} height="50" width="50"></img> {t.full_name}  
        </li>  
    );  
});
```

As expected the logos are not displayed I get the icon not found image next to each team name. I tried using eval like so:

```
    <img src={eval(t.abbreviation + "_Logo")} height="50" width="50"></img> {t.full_name}
```

but it gave me the error:

> Unhandled Rejection (ReferenceError): Abbr1_Logo is not defined

Is there a way I can accomplish this?

By the way if I hard code one of the imports into this line it works, but of course all of the teams have the same logo, so at least I know that the files are being imported correctly and that the code resolves it when the imported variable is used.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your imports can not be evaluated at compile-time (when webpack / typescript are running) because the information about the teams is not know yet.

What you can do is using the `copy-webpack-plugin` to copy the logos over and then use

```
src={`/resources/team-logos/${t.abbreviation}_logo.svg`)}
```

Make sure the copy-webpack-plugin copies things into the right folder, in my code it's `/resources/team-logos`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add your images as object and object keys can be like that

```
const images = {
 Abbr1_Logo: "../resources/img/team1_logo.svg"
 Abbr2_Logo: "../resources/img/team2_logo.svg"
}
```

and then you can require the image an do the concatenation on the object level like

```
images[`${t.abbreviation}_logo`]
```